# Receiving Invalid number of Arguments - SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I need to create a view named `A9T5` that will use the `A9` table to display the non-null States, the number of people in the state, the number of different JobTitles held by the people in the state, and the average number of people per JobTitle in the state.

The state abbreviations should be displayed in upper case. The average should be rounded to one digit after the decimal point. The four column headings should be `State`, `People`, `Different_Jobs` and `People_Per_Job`. The rows should be sorted by `State`.

Note: The average in column 4 is just the value in column 2 divided by the value in column 3. For instance, there are 369 people from California. Collectively, the 369 people hold 14 different `JobTitle`s. This results in an average of 369/14=26.3571 which rounds to 26.4.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

```
SELECT Upper(State) as State, 
       Count(*) as People, Count(DISTINCT JobTitle) as Different_Jobs,
       Round((Count(*) / Count(DISTINCT InitCap(JobTitle),1)) as People_Per_Job
FROM A9
WHERE State is NOT NULL
GROUP BY Upper(State)
ORDER BY Upper(State);
```

I keep getting the error, `invalid number of arguments`.

What do i need to do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing 1 ')' in

```
Round((Count(*) / Count(DISTINCT InitCap(JobTitle),1)) as
```

should be

```
 Round(( Count(*) / Count(DISTINCT InitCap(JobTitle)) ),1)
```